# Adding file path of the image to be displayed in report in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

so i need to put pictures in a report (some entry to have and some entry not to have), but the data need to be editable in excel, so i figure if i find a way to put it in path form (c:\folder\picture.bmp) is feasible, just don't know how.

I tried hyperlink, OLE object, simple text... nothing works. My VBA knowledge is almost zero.

Any suggestions?
Tnx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question clearly. You want to have a picture in excel that is editable. So you want changes in the picture from excel saved in the original file (c:\folder\picture.bmp)?
(I wanted to make a comment but i don't have enough reputation for this)

Maybe this could help in VBA:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Picture()   
Dim myPict as Picture 
PictureLoc = "C:-Path-.png"
Set myPict = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(PictureLoc)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, tnx for reply. No, i want to put path in access and that path i want to be able to edit in excel. And from path i want picture displayed in report.